# ORM (NHibernate), DDD and saving complex entities

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I am new to NHibernate (and frankly to DDD concepts) so my question may be simple or irrelevant, but I would be very thankful if someone helps me with my confusions.

In my application I am using DDD and NHibernate as ORM.

With simple entities it works fine, but now I am at a stage where my Entities are getting very complex (so entity A contains entity B and array of entity C; and each entity C contains D and few other parameters and so on...)

My client app is talking to WCF services (that talk to db) over internet and hence speed (and payload size matters a lot). In few cases, I have to send an array of these complex DTOs from service to client, then the client updates few values in A and sends it back to the server for saving/updating.

To decrease the payload, I am trying to remove the unused property values from B and C entities in my DTOs by nullifying them in my mapper (I am not using automapper etc) while sending data from Service to client.

Now when it comes to saving the entity back to db, what should I do? If I pass back the entity A with null values in few variables of B and C (that I had nullified manually in mapper), NHibernate will try to save B and C as well when I save A. I want to save just A, and ask NHibernate not to save anything from B or C.

Any help, will be blessing to me.

Thanks in advance,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in this case could be found in projections. In a nutshell:

- Keep your mapping correct and complex.
- But when selecting data, put only needed columns into `select` clause.

And this could be done via `Projections`. Nice detailed explanation could be found here:

http://shareyour-experience.blogspot.cz/2011/07/exploring-nhibernate-projections-and.html

Documentation:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-projection

When data will come back on the server, your fully mapped entities will be able to persist all properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot Radim for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Once entities become complex, it is best to decouple the notion of commands that invoke behavior on entities from the structure of the entity itself. (A command in this case means a DTO representing a request to perform an operation). You can have a command that looks like this:

```
class DoSomethingToAnEntityCommand
{
  public string EntityId { get; set; }
  public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

When the application service handles this command, it would load up the required entity and invoke applicable behaviors on that entity and the commit the transaction.

The next step is to decouple queries from commands. When you retrieve an entity from the database to be returned as a DTO, you don't have to use the same retrieval mechanism as you would if you were loading an entity to be acted upon. As you point out, query requirements can vary even for a single entity. Some queries only need part of an entity and it can be too costly to load the entire entity. There are various ways to load only part of an entity. As stated by Radim Köhler, you can use NHibernate projections. Another option is to go direct with a SQL query, outside of NHibernate. With either option, the objects returned are not intended to be persisted back - they are only to be used to fulfill query requirements.

When you need to invoke behavior on an entity, you don't need to pass the entire object graph representing the entity. You only need to pass the ID of the appropriate entity as well as any arguments required to perform the given operation as denoted in the code sample. This is where NHibernate comes in - it can load the entity by ID and track any changes made during the operation to be persisted back to the database.

Comment: Thanks Lev for your explanation. Unfortunately, I can't mark two answers as accepted. Thanks again.